# Is there a really well designed and performant generic streaming camera viewer for iOS?

Tags: ios, software-recommendation, camera, streaming, video

With the proliferation of cheap streaming camera hardware recently it's never been easier to get into generic 'CCTV' cameras.

On the Mac side there is good, well designed software available for viewing the output of the cameras, like [SecuritySpy](http://www.bensoftware.com/securityspy/), however I don’t know of similar quality apps on the iOS side.

Some are very poor in UI terms (looking like they would fit in on iOS6). Others have been unable to optimize or deliver performance in the app.

Requirements:

- Must support generic hardware (e.g. ONVIF & RTSP compatible).
- Doing extra for a vertically integrated product where the app is good
  is fine, but not if it will only support their own hardware.
- UI - does it follow the Apple HIG or have a modern design of its own?
- UI - must have decent accommodations for 2 to 4 screens using the space well. Bonus points for customizable or scriptable sizing of the various feeds.
- Performance: add a new 4K stream in less than 8 seconds

Currently:

- [ICamViewer](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/ip-cam-viewer-pro/id402656416) which performs quite well, but doesn't meet the UI requirements.
- [VGX RTSPPlayer](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/vxg-rtsp-player/id1070125481) which has a better UI, but is slow to launch
  camera streams and doesn't appear to be able to show a matrix of
  multiple cameras simultaneously.

Ideally I'd like one app (or an update) that combines the performance of one and the UI of the other.

Does anyone have any suggestions for good CCTV client apps based on these criteria?